# Reading file attached with paperclip -- No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why am I getting no such file or directory when I use a symbol in my path?  Paperclip shows :rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename as the default path.  The file is in public/system/attachments/email.txt, but I want to be able to add a file with any name.

```
  has_attached_file :email,
  :url => "public/system/attachments/:filename",
  :path => "public/system/attachments/:filename"


def read_original_header
@original_email = File.read("public/system/attachments/:filename")
end
```

No such file or directory - public/system/attachments/:filename

Comment: What about something like: `File.read(email.path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the 'symbol' interpolation is a Paperclip convention, this convention is not shared by the standard Ruby File class.

Comment: There has to be a way to open a file without knowing the name

Comment: Your question was why you were getting a no such file or directory error with your code.  If you know the directory you want to look in, you can use the Dir.entries() method to get a list of files in that directory, after which you could open the one you want.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html